# How to run two services in docker?

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask

I'm totally new to docker and I have a flask as API service and react app can I use just one docker to run both python app.py and npm start together? Tnx.

Comment: Yes you can, but this is not best practice. One docker container should run one service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good approach is to separate them into two different containers. And run all the containers with docker-compose command. Then you will get all advantages of container isolation, but in the same time (by default) your apps will be at the same network and will get a possibility to transfer data between them by container name.

But ofc you can create sh-script that running two different apps in the background and put it into your CMD command in Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.